# How to enforce generic parameter to allow undefined

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to use a wrapper for different API requests where I don't always know what the response will be and I don't know whether the request will be successful. I would like to be able to specify the expected return type of my function in a few cases without making it mandatory so my first attempt was

```
function fetch<T=any>(){
let body:T = undefined
// fetch the request
return body
}
```

Obviously the compiler will mark body here with

> 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be
> unrelated to 'undefined'.

so next I tried to do

```
function fetch<T extends any|undefined = any>(){
let body:T = undefined
// fetch the request
return body
}
```

but this gives me the error:

> 'undefined' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'unknown'.

Now I am out of ideas and I am not sure what the right language is to describe the problem and google it. If somebody could point me in the right direction, that would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Why not just add the `| undefined` if it will always be there. If `T` already contains `|undefined` it will do no harm, it it does not it will add it to the result. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEWODNACwB4AVOAXjgEMUBPAPgAoBKOAbwCg4e4AbfHABGEACZ0AXHHIAfOKlHAEmFMFGU4TFEj58AhDQDO0uHIVKValt14B6W3gKE4MQsDhRgARyTBDMGx5PGCQoXBFxTgBfTk4BeBANBHwiYnYaKW0AWyFgKDgo5hYgA

Comment: I now, it is not strictly related to your answer, but some time ago I was experimenting with server requests typings. [Here](https://catchts.com/api) you can find my article. It might be helpfull in some cases

Comment: @Titian, your right that solves the question that I have asked. Thanks!